# "...its answers may be merged with another identical question. "

Tags: support, close-reasons

When a question is closed, because it's an exact duplicate, it says:

> **closed as exact duplicate by Chuck Norris 8 hours ago.**
>
> This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with another identical question. See the FAQ.

What does "...its answers may be merged with another identical question." mean?
Is it just a way of saying that the answers also fit to another question or is it an announcement that it might happen that these answers will move to the other question?

Comment: Chuck Norris can close a question alone.

Comment: Both. Moderators have the power to merge two questions into one. It is not often used though (for practical reasons: merger doesn't make sense unless the two questions are *really* identical).